# Validation User input using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am novice in php, html and javascript. My aim is to check and validate the user input. My code is working only for one input field which is not in loop. In a moment, I want to check multiple input fields from loop the reply of the code is "* Wrong Insert: undefined, position: null".

Would you be so kind and tell me what am I doing wrong ?

javscript block

```
    function ValidationSubmit()
    {

         var DatabaseIndex = document.getElementById("3").getAttribute("name");

         var CheckInt    = document.getElementById("3");
         var CheckIntVal = CheckInt.value;
         const a=-10;
         if( a < 0 )
         {
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "* Wrong insert : " + CheckIntVal + ", position: " + DatabaseIndex ;
          return false;
         }

         else
         {
          return true;
         }
```

php block for calling validation function ValidationSubmit()

```
echo '<form method="POST" target="_top" action="SaveForm.php?UID='.$UID.'" onsubmit="return ValidationSubmit()">';
```

php block for user input

```
$j = 0;
while($j<=10)
        {
        $ID    = strval($j);
        echo "<td><input type='text' id='$ID' name='$ID' value='$value[$j]'  ></td>";

        $j++;
        }
```

Comment: Just like PHP, JavaScript supports `while` or `for` loops. Where you have `3` hard-coded in your JS, just use a loop and increment a variable.

Comment: However, i your JS, you are creating a constant set to `-10` and then you are returning an error if that constant is less than zero which is always true. I'm not really clear on what your logic is actually intending to do.

Comment: Dear Chris, many thanks for your reply. I tried to iterate in function but without succes. The hard condition to fulfill the true  in if block will change in future, this is only the way how I display the results of my effort. Would you be so kind and and explained to me your suggestion in example ?

Comment: Now I am able to run the loop, ge the correct ID of an element, but I cannot the value from the element. If I chek if the element has attribute value, I get the answer false. { let i = 1;
  while(i<=4)
  {
   var DataBaseIndex = document.getElementById(i).getAttribute("id");
   var CheckInt    = document.getElementById(i);
   var CheckIntVal = CheckInt.hasAttribute("value");
   console.log(CheckInt);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += "* Wrong Integer: " + CheckIntVal + ", id " + DataBaseIndex;

   i++;
  }
  return false;
 }